# She is snuggling

Tags: word-usage, word-request

She is cold.

She needs a blanket.

```
She is snuggling.
```

[image]

Is snuggling describe well as the image?

Basically snuggle is in a position that is feeling comfort.

How about if he/she is feeling no comfortable and bending himself/herself to be like a ball? What should we describe this kind of action?

Comment: Did you check on the meaning of [snuggle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snuggle) in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not quite sure the meaning.

Comment: Then you need to tell us why in your question.

Comment: I have add a little explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a specific verb for that, but I would personally describe the action as:

> She lay in a [**fetal position**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetal_position).

**How about if he/she is feeling no comfortable and bending himself/herself to be like a ball? What should we describe this kind of action?**

From the Wikipedia link:

> Many people assume this position when sleeping, especially when the body becomes cold.

**Sample Usage (via Google):**

[image]

**Image Search (via Google):**

[image]